# formatting horizontal and vertical images in Settings?

Tags: media, options

I have several custom media sizes we always use.

vertical: 95x117, 130x160
horizontal: 440x304, 220x152
home: 260x160

Is there anyway to set the thumbnail, medium and large to vertical parameters and horizontal ones? Or is it better to leave the defaults (150x150, 300, 1024) so that I can set the sizes using width and height parameters as needed?

Thanks!
Donna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would **not** alter the core intermediate image sizes. If you have custom image sizes, register them using `add_image_size()`. e.g.

```
function mytheme_add_custom_image_sizes() {
     // Add "vertical" image
    add_image_size( 'vertical-a', 95, 117, true );
    add_image_size( 'vertical-b', 130, 160, true );
    // Add "horizontal" image
    add_image_size( 'horizontal-a', 440, 304, true );
    add_image_size( 'horizontal-b', 220, 152, true );
    // Add "home" image
    add_image_size( 'home', 260, 160, true )
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_add_custom_image_sizes' );
```

Now, your registered custom image sizes can be used in any of the core image-related functions, to return the image in one of your custom sizes.

Comment: You're welcome! Does "thanks so much!" mean that this solution worked for you? If so, please *accept* it, by clicking the checkmark beneath the vote count. If this solution *didn't* work for you, please comment to explain why, so that we can find a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Some media size names are [reserved eg thumbnail, medium and large.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size#Reserved_Image_Size_Names) but it [may be possible to customise their sizes from admin screen](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Media_SubPanel). and besides if you really want to use your custom sizes, you could always edit your theme to use your custom sizes instead of wordpress sizes